# Finding a DOM Node's attribute (OR, to be more specific, a div's class)

Tags: javascript, dom, attributes

Here's my code:

```
<body class="asdf">
        <span>hey! <div class='hideContent'>test</div> the ultimate experience</span>
        <span id="blarg">original</span>
</body>

<script>

        function pullElementsOut(searchClass, searchNode) {
                var childNodes = (searchNode || document.body).childNodes, cnLength = childNodes.length;
                var excludes = 'html,head,style,title,link,meta,script,object,iframe';
                while (cnLength--) {
                        var currentNode = childNodes[cnLength];
                        alert(currentNode.nodeType+" "+currentNode.localName + " " + currentNode.hasAttributes());
                        if (currentNode.nodeType === 1 && (excludes + ',').indexOf(currentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() + ',') === -1) {
                                arguments.callee(searchClass, currentNode);
                        }
                        if (currentNode.nodeType !== 2) {
                                continue;
                        }
                }
        }
        pullElementsOut('hideContent');
</script>
```

As you can see, I have an unfinished function pullElementsOut.   I want to identify the "hideContent" class of that div.  My eventual goal is to pull all the elements out and delete the now empty div.  But, I cant seem to figure out how to access the class attributes of a node, much less modify it.

Any help?

Comment: you want the `className` property of the element

Comment: Take a look at jQuery. There you can just use css strings to find dom elments e.g. `$("div.hideContent")`

Comment: Cant use jquery.  Trying to make ultra portable code :(  Also, I just learned that nodes and elements are the same thing.  What the hell.  Why have 2 different names for the same thing?

Comment: [elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-745549614) are a *type* of [node](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247). Everything in the DOM is a node, some nodes are elements. Use the `className` DOM property, it is the simplest and most compatible access method.

Answer (score 0):

not sure but I think what you want can be done using `getAttribute('class')` method.